# Xamarin LocationManager.RequestSingleUpdate always throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, xamarin, location

For some reason whenever I implement `ILocationListener` and implement the necessary interface methods this call always crashes on me:

```
LocMgr.RequestSingleUpdate(provider, this, null);
```

It throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid listener: null` although it's obviously impossible for `this` to be `null`. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues here.

1. I needed to inherit from `Java.Lang.Object`
2. I needed to make sure I wasn't providing new implementations of `Dispose` or `Handle`.

Once I removed these the function call worked as expected.